# How to number nodes when creating decision trees in R?

Tags: r

In `R` I am creating a data frame of the structure of decision trees. The issue I'm facing is, I have to number the nodes of the trees in a certain way that will allow me to plot them later. However, Im struggling to find a good way to number the nodes. Hopefully my example below will explain the issue.

For example, if I have a column in my data frame that describes the path or direction of the nodes, like so:

```
df <- data.frame(
  var = c("P", "L", "R", "RL", "RR",
          "P", "L", "R" , "RL", "RR", "LL", "LR", "RRL", "RRR")
  
)
```

Here, `P` means the parent node, `L` means left node, `R` means right node, `RL` means the left node from the previous right node etc... The diagram below shows what the decision trees made from `df$var` would look like:
[image: decision trees]

So, as we can see, every time we reach a `P` in `df$var`, we start a new decision tree, as it is the parent.

Now, I want to try and number the nodes, so I can plot them. I initially tried numbering the nodes sequentially, like so:

```
df <- df %>%
group_by(newVal = cumsum(var == "P")) %>%
  mutate(node = 1:length(var)) %>%
  ungroup()  %>%
  select(-newVal)
 df
 var    node
 P         1
 L         2
 R         3
 RL        4
 RR        5
 P         1
 L         2
 R         3
 RL        4
 RR        5
 LL        6
 LR        7
 RRL       8
 RRR       9
```

For clarity, that would look like this:
[image: numbered decision tree]

But as you can see (mainly in the 2nd tree), due to the original ordering of `df$var`, it results in a non-intuitive numbering of the nodes. This presents a problem when I try to plot the tree.

The issue is, when Im plotting the trees, I have to create data frames (for each tree) with 2 columns. That is, `from` and `to`, where we go *from* node *x* *to* node *y*. Using the 2nd image as an example, my data frames for plotting would look like this:

```
tree.1.Edges <- data.frame(
  from = c(1,1,3,3),
  to = c(2,3,4,5)
)

tree.2.edges <- data.frame(
  from = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,5,5),
  to =   c(2,3,6,7,4,5,8,9)
)
```

Im finding it difficult to come up with a way to automate the process of creating the tree edges data frames using my method of sequentially numbering the nodes. Does anyone have any suggestions as to a better way I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Prefix

This is my solution. It returns a list of the edges with correctly numbered nodes.
The Nodes are numbered like this:

- Parent node number < Child node number
- Left node number < Right node number

## Code

```r
library(tidyverse)


df <- data.frame(
  var = c("P", "L", "R", "RL", "RR",
          "P", "L", "R" , "RL", "RR", "LL", "LR", "RRL", "RRR"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE # important for character operations
)

#enumerate tree ids
# a new tree is initialized when a parent node "P" is initialized
df$tree <-cumsum(df$var=="P") # Cumsum increments for every TRUE by one
 
#sort nodes so that Left nodes are in front of Right nodes
# and every deeper level of the tree is numbered after
# the preceeding level
df <- df %>% group_by(tree) %>% mutate(level = nchar(var)) %>%
  group_by(tree) %>% arrange(level, # arrange by level first
                             # custom alphabet function where P comes first
                             # As L comes in front of R in the alphabet
                             # longer strings are
                             # correctly sorted
                             ifelse(var=="P",1,match(LETTERS,var)+1),
                            .by_group = TRUE)


# define the nodes as row numbers resetting at every tree
df <- df %>% group_by(tree) %>% mutate(node = row_number())

## At this point the nodes are numbered according to your specifications

# Find out parent node by deleting the last character from every node name (var)
df <- df %>% group_by(tree) %>% mutate(parent_node_name=substr(var,0,nchar(var)-1))

# define parent node of P as NA
df$parent_node_name[df$var=="P"] <- NA

# define parent nodes vars with still empty parent node name as "P"
df$parent_node_name[df$parent_node_name==""] <- "P"

# Match parent node names to node numbers
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(tree) %>% 
  mutate(parent_node_num = match(parent_node_name,var))

# split the dataframe into a list of dfs, one for each tree
list_edges <- split(df,df$tree)

# for every dataframe in the list, replace by a result dataframe (res)
list_edges <- lapply(list_edges, function(df_tree){
  res <- data.frame(
    from = df_tree$parent_node_num,
    to = df_tree$node
  )
  # delete NAs from result
  res <- res[!is.na(res$from),]
  return(res)
})

# Show result
list_edges

# $`1`
# from to
# 2    1  2
# 3    1  3
# 4    3  4
# 5    3  5
# 
# $`2`
# from to
# 2    1  2
# 3    1  3
# 4    3  4
# 5    3  5
# 6    2  6
# 7    2  7
# 8    5  8
# 9    5  9
```

The code is quite convoluted, but you can insert `df` at any point to look at the intermediate results. Or simply post a comment.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for your help... I was struggling with this one for a while.